# Google Cast IPV6 Compliancy?

Tags: ios, ipv6, google-cast

Is Google Cast's latest SDK for iOS IPV6 Compliant? I can't seem to find any documentation stating it is and I've already put in a ticket and its been over two weeks and no response. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Devin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be compliant. If you run into any issues, please oen a bug on our Cast SDK issue tracker.